# External login system for my website

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, authentication

I am currently developing a website that offers many services for local customers, lets call it "payiteasy.com". As the number of users who are registered in this website is increasing and the number of services offered too, I began to think to build an external login system.

To explain more about what I am trying to do, let's say that one of my website registered users is also registered and constantly uses a website called "abc.com" I want to allow my user to validate his credentials or login to abc.com using payiteasy.com username and password.

I think what I am trying to do is similar to when you login to some websites using your Facebook, Google, Yahoo or Twitter account. I was also reading about Facebook Login Architecture and maybe I need to do something like that!

I don't really know much about this but I want to have a right start: how to let my users login to other websites using their payiteasy account and maybe after that I can allow them to use some of its services.

Payiteasy is built using PHP and JavaScript and it uses an MVC framework. Where should I start with this?

Comment: You're looking for [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). Helper libraries exist.

Comment: Or you could use webservice(tutorial to get you started: http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json), to access the remote database where your user's credentials exist.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I see that I need to have a look and work with OAuth. I had a quick look, my biggest concern here is security as payiteasy.com will offer services that include financial transactions, is OAuth secure enough ?!

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want to do is having oAuth concept which google, facebook and other site follows to allow external login.

It is a very popular approach nowadays when you want to allow login to multiple sites with same credentials.

For this, you need to basically have secret key and a public key which you will ask the other site to send for validating user and if it is verified you will pass an oAuth token, this token will be further used to authenticate a user without asking them to log in again from other site.

For more details look [here](http://oauth.net/code/)

Comment: thank you fro your answer. I see that Outh has two different versions, but I dont know if its secure enough..

Comment: It is secure in a way that you need secret key and public key to interact and it is quite secure and ya there are two versions of oauth in which oauth2 is latest version and is widely used.

Comment: nevermind :-) I have actually read the full question now :P